# Cross-Site Duplicates - Ethics?

Tags: discussion

I've answered a couple of questions today which were cross-site duplicates (not by the same user) for questions over on Science Fiction & Fantasy.

Now, I'm aware that there is overlap between M&TV and SF&F but I'm wondering about my ethical responsibilities here.

I linked in the SF&F Question and Answer and a gist of the content (lifted directly and quoted) from SF&F so that **our** answer could be considered complete...so I've done the right thing in providing attribution.

But is that enough?

Should I deny myself the rep too by making the answer a Community Wiki (which isn't the intended purpose of a CW)...

...or just content myself with having been able to provide an answer *because* I'm a member of both sites and knew where to look...and enjoy the rep 'bonus'.

The latter feels right...almost, hence this question.

Comment: Yes, that's enough. CW is not and never was for the purpose of eschewing the concept of reputation. Afterall, we source from external sites to a great deal each day here, that is perfectly fine if done properly and shouldn't be any different if those external sites happen to belong to the SE network, too.